# how to solve API SDK PHP error?

Tags: php, api, xampp

I have a API php SDk to connect with database of online store and i save on htdos of xampp but when i open an index of that file i get the error :

**Warning**: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\SellerCenterSDK-PHP-master\samples\endpoint\product/../../../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SellerCenterSDK-PHP-master\samples\endpoint\product\getProducts.php on line 9

**Fatal error**: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\SellerCenterSDK-PHP-master\samples\endpoint\product/../../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\SellerCenterSDK-PHP-master\samples\endpoint\product\getProducts.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "composer install" in the project root, since the master branch does not automatically include all dependencies.

Comment: how can i run it? but i have composer instaled in my laptop